# Продавать лекарство (в значении давать лекарство)

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Возможно ли использовать *продавать* (приставка *про-* к глаголу *давать*) в значении выражения *продавать лекарство* (т. е. давать лекарство, пройти курс лекарства, проколоть лекарство).
Или слово *продавать* употребляется только в значении: "отдавать другому за деньги" или "предательство"?

Comment: Раздавать, выдавать, но не продавать.

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос. Технически, то есть с точки зрения морфемики, 'продавать' возможно... Но звучит-то непонятно, слишком привычной стала коннотация 'продавать' = 'давать за деньги'.

Та же проблема с некоторыми другими глаголами с приставкой 'про': "Он продумал всю ночь" — вот что это значит? Потратил всю ночь на размышления или обдумал, что будет делать ночью? "Он прогулял весь день" — в смысле гулял весь день или пропустил весь рабочий день?..

**Ответ на ваш вопрос**: технически использовать можно, это не будет ошибкой. Но надо убедиться, что читатель правильно поймёт мысль. Как по мне, так легче переделать предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза на эту тему: *Хорошо **пропить курс витаминов**, БАД, адаптогенов типа элеутерококка ― сделав это на растущей Луне.* [Астрологический прогноз, 2003.02.14]

***Пропить  курс*** – это разг. или спец.  Более корректно: ***пройти курс*** лечения.

Приставка ПРО – многозначная, в этих примерах она имеет значение действия в течение определенного отрезка **времени**.

А вот приставка в слове «***продать***»  не выделяется, слово происходит от праслав. *pro-dadi̯a, из про- и дать; первонач. продажа — «плата за то, что дано кому-либо». Ср. др.-инд. рrаdā́nаm ср. р. «отдавание». [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/продать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Выражение "продавать курс лекарства" вряд ли используется, так как его смысл трудно понять (если только как профессиональный термин).